# Points to be noted before transferring Wordpress Website from Shared hosting to VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, virtualhost, vps, shared-hosting

- I have a wordpress website which is hosted on Shared Hosting but I found so many problems in shared hosting as my website is too heavy and the content will regularly get updated and there are so many plugins which I need to use on that website.
- Now I have decided to switch my hosting to VPS as I will get 2GB of physical memory with it.
- I wanted to know what are the major points which I have to take care of before switching my hosting to VPS

Note: Service Provider are same for VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have purchased the self managed VPS. Make sure you have following services included with VPS

1) Installation of the cPanel, Plesk or DirectAdmin control panel is done during VPS provisioning. cPanel license is activated.

2) You have ready to go Hosting environment so you do not need to setup/install any additional software at your end.

3) cPanel/WHM firewall is primarily configured for initial security hardening.

4) Operating System is up to date with all security patches applied.

5) PHP, MYSQL Apache versions matched with shared web server and are compatible with your website too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i just wanted to know what should i kept as a backup from my wordpress website.

Comment: You should take the complete backup of WordPress websites. You can take the complete backup through any good WordPress backup plugin. Also, while you migrate your websites to VPS, "cPanel to cPanel migration" would be the easiest method for migration. https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/921/How-to-transfer-a-domain-from-one-cPanel-server-to-other-cPanel-server.html

Comment: @AnkitPathak.  Everything. In fact, I find server migrations great times to test backup plans and how well they restore... testing that lots of server admins overlook....